# Running a selenese Selenium test on the command-line using Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, command-line, selenium

I used the Selenium IDE in Firefox to record a test suite in selenese, and I'd like to run these tests on the command-line using Chrome. (I'm running Mac OS X).

I'm clearly doing something wrong, because when I try to do so, it runs in Firefox instead.

I downloaded the chromedriver for OS X, and the selenium-server-standalone jar file, and put them both in /usr/local/bin. I thought the following command would do want I want, but it runs the tests inside of Firefox instead of Chrome. (Note, I'm testing a local app running at `http://localhost:8001`).

```
$ java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver \
 -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar \
 -htmlSuite "*chrome" http://localhost:8001 /Users/lorin/selenium/suite.html /Users/lorin//selenium/results.html
```

The output looks like this:

```
Jun 19, 2012 4:32:40 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
16:32:45.880 INFO - Java: Apple Inc. 20.8-b03-424
16:32:45.881 INFO - OS: Mac OS X 10.7.4 x86_64
16:32:45.887 INFO - v2.24.1, with Core v2.24.1. Built from revision 17205
16:32:45.972 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
16:32:45.973 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
16:32:45.973 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
16:32:45.974 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
16:32:45.974 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
16:32:46.018 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@3b75078b
16:32:46.018 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
16:32:46.024 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
16:32:46.025 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@6db3f829
jar:file:/usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar!/customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME
16:32:46.103 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
16:32:47.013 INFO - Launching Firefox...
16:32:47.734 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
16:33:00.781 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
16:33:00.783 INFO - Received posted results
16:33:01.537 INFO - Killing Firefox...
16:33:01.608 INFO - Shutting down...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `*googlechrome` instead for chrome. That should fix it. *chrome is used to run firefox in another mode.

Comment: Hmm, am not sure about that as I have not tried to run HTML suite. If its throwing you error saying "chromedriver path was not found" add the path in your command. -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="pathtochromedriver"

Answer (score 3):

To run it in Firefox you should use command ***chrome**

To run it in Chrome you should use command ***googlechrome**

And to run it in Internet Explorer you should use ***iexplore**